# How can I make a progress bar while copying a directory with cp?

Tags: bash, progress-bar, cp

I suppose I could compare the number of files in the source directory to the number of files in the target directory as cp progresses, or perhaps do it with folder size instead? I tried to find examples, but all bash progress bars seem to be written for copying single files. I want to copy a bunch of files (or a directory, if the former is not possible).

Comment: You've hit [Bash FAQ # 44](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/044).  Take a look and see if any of the suggestions there are useful.

Answer (score 78):

You can also use `rsync` instead of `cp` like this:

`rsync -Pa source destination`

Which will give you a progress bar and estimated time of completion. Very handy.

Comment: Right, `rsync --progress /path/to/origin /path/to/destination` is awesome and is available on all systems.

Comment: Works when copying a single file as well.

Comment: Happen to know the speed comparison between rsync and cp?

Comment: @Allasso Tough to say because there's so many options and situations which affect it. It can be slower for certain sets files, especially with a small CPU, because it's analyzing/syncing not copying, and encrypting files (when over a network, iirc). For example see https://superuser.com/questions/109780/how-to-speed-up-rsync or https://superuser.com/questions/153176/how-to-rsync-a-large-file-with-as-little-cpu-and-bandwidth-expense-as-possible/1020737#1020737

Comment: If copying several files, consider using `gcp` or `advcpmv`, with more useful progress bar.

Answer (score 26):

To show a progress bar while doing a recursive copy of files & folders & subfolders (including links and file attributes), you can use `gcp` (easily installed in Ubuntu and Debian by running "sudo apt-get install gcp"):

```
gcp -rf SRC DEST
```

Here is the typical output while copying a large folder of files:

```
Copying 1.33 GiB  73% |#####################      | 230.19 M/s ETA:  00:00:07
```

Notice that it shows just one progress bar for the whole operation, whereas if you want a single progress bar per file, you can use `rsync`:

```
rsync -ah --progress SRC DEST
```

Comment: gcp is Python-based. PLEASE DO NOT USE IN PRODUCTION. I did not check, but it seems does not support hardlinks, special attributes and so on .

Comment: gcp doesn't work in a remote terminal (for example via ssh).

Comment: @M.Moro gcp through ssh works for me with: `dbus-launch gcp -pR src dst`

Comment: `gcp` immediately crashed when executing the command above on a raspberry pi 4. not sure why

Answer (score 6):

You may have a look at the tool `vcp`. Thats a simple copy tool with two progress bars: One for the current file, and one for overall.

**EDIT**

Here is the link to the sources: http://members.iinet.net.au/~lynx/vcp/
Manpage can be found here: http://linux.die.net/man/1/vcp

Most distributions have a package for it.

Comment: I was hoping for something that doesn't require compiling external tools. I just want to see my directory get copied. Is it really so difficult?

Comment: @Anonymouse added a second answer, maybe this would be an alternative for you. But thats my last idea :(

Comment: As said below, rsync is available on all systems (even Mac OS), as opposed to vcp.

Comment: The http://members.iinet.net.au/~lynx/vcp/ link is broken. There seems to be a current fork at https://github.com/gdm85/curses-vcp with a last commit of May 29, 2016. I was able to compile it just fine on Fedora 23. 

An independent `vcp` with a similar concept is at https://github.com/lynix/vcp but I have not tried it.

Answer (score 4):

Here another solution: Use the tool `bar`

You could invoke it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
filesize=$(du -sb ${1} | awk '{ print $1 }')
tar -cf - -C ${1} ./ | bar --size ${filesize} | tar -xf - -C ${2}
```

You have to go the way over tar, and it will be inaccurate on small files. Also you must take care that the target directory exists. But it is a way.

Comment: Early on, I thought about tarring the folder before moving it, but thought it would lack too much in elegance. I was wrong. It works as expected and might actually be a better solution in some cases. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

My preferred option is [Advanced Copy](https://github.com/jarun/advcpmv), as it uses the original `cp` source files.

```
$ wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/coreutils/coreutils-8.21.tar.xz
$ tar xvJf coreutils-8.21.tar.xz
$ cd coreutils-8.21/
$ wget --no-check-certificate wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jarun/advcpmv/master/advcpmv-0.8-8.32.patch
$ patch -p1 -i advcpmv-0.8-8.32.patch
$ ./configure
$ make
```

> The new programs are now located in src/cp and src/mv. You may choose to replace your existing commands:

```
$ sudo cp src/cp /usr/local/bin/cp
$ sudo cp src/mv /usr/local/bin/mv
```

Then you can use `cp` as usual, or specify `-g` to show the progress bar:

```
$ cp -g src dest
```

Comment: The link to the patch at zwicke.org is broken but it's on github at https://github.com/atdt/advcpmv. Perhaps someone with more skills than I will update @elboletaire's steps.

Comment: This should be selected answer. Better progress bar than rsync if copying several files. Better than gcp because reusing standard cp code from coreutils. Advantage of gcp is that it is distributed as a standard package.

Comment: Would be worth mentioning that you need to use `-g` option with this patched `cp` in order to get the progress bar.

Answer (score 2):

A **simple unix** way  is to go to the destination directory and do `watch -n 5 du -s` . Perhaps make it more pretty by showing as a bar . This can help in environments where you have just the standard unix utils and no scope of installing additional files . du-sh is the key , watch is to just do every 5 seconds. 
**Pros** : Works on any unix system  **Cons** : No Progress Bar

Answer (score 2):

To add another option, you can use `cpv`. It uses `pv` to imitate the usage of `cp`.

It works like `pv` but you can use it to recursively copy directories

[image]

You can get it [here](https://ownyourbits.com/2017/09/13/copy-with-a-progress-bar-with-cpv/)

Comment: how do i use it recursively for directories?
i tried `cpv -r src dst` but it prints `too few args`

Answer (score 0):

There's a tool `pv` to do this exact thing: http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml

There's a ubuntu version in apt

Comment: `pv` is not an option because it won't save permissions or any other file attributes.  `pv source > dest` will give you a nice progress bar but the file dest is not going to be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like

```
find . -type f | pv -s $(find . -type f | wc -c) | xargs -i cp {} --parents /DEST/$(dirname {})
```

It finds all the files in the current directory, pipes that through PV while giving PV an estimated size so the progress meter works and then piping that to a CP command with the --parents flag so the DEST path matches the SRC path.

One problem I have yet to overcome is that if you issue this command

```
find /home/user/test -type f | pv -s $(find . -type f | wc -c) | xargs -i cp {} --parents /www/test/$(dirname {})
```

the destination path becomes /www/test/home/user/test/....FILES... and I am unsure how to tell the command to get rid of the '/home/user/test' part.  That why I have to run it from inside the SRC directory.

Answer (score 0):

Check the source code for *progress_bar* in the below git repository of mine

https://github.com/Kiran-Bose/supreme

Also try custom bash script package **supreme** to verify how progress bar work with **cp** and **mv** comands

Functionality overview

(1)Open Apps
----Firefox
----Calculator
----Settings

(2)Manage Files
----Search
----Navigate
----Quick access

```
            |----Select File(s)
            |----Inverse Selection
            |----Make directory
            |----Make file
                                          |----Open
                                          |----Copy
                                          |----Move
                                          |----Delete
                                          |----Rename
                                          |----Send to Device
                                          |----Properties
```

(3)Manage Phone
----Move/Copy from phone
----Move/Copy to phone
----Sync folders

(4)Manage USB
----Move/Copy from USB
----Move/Copy to USB

Answer (score 0):

There is command `progress`, https://github.com/Xfennec/progress, coreutils progress viewer.

Just run progress in another terminal to see the copy/move progress. For continuous monitoring use -M flag.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).