# How to follow the progress of a linux command?

Tags: linux, command

I am currently working with a large data set where even the file format conversion takes at least an hour per subject and as a result I am often unsure whether my command has been executed or the program has frozen. I was wondering whether anyone has a tip to how to follow the progress of the commands/scripts I am trying to run in linux?

Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Which commands? Some of them may have options for verbose output.

Comment: Shell scripts can be run by `sh -x` instead of `sh` to show the commands prior to executing them.

Comment: If you produces a log or any kind of file, you can run `tail -f` on this file.

Comment: If all else fails, you can spawn `top` in another console and monitor the CPU usage of your command.

Comment: The command I am currently waiting output from is `find . -mindepth 4 -type d -exec tractor -d -r -b preproc RunStages:1 Interactive:FALSE '{}' \;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make a progress bar while copying a directory with cp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7128575/how-can-i-make-a-progress-bar-while-copying-a-directory-with-cp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the long-lasting command produces some output in a file `foo.out`, you could do `watch ls -l foo.out` or `tail -f foo.out`

You could also list `/proc/$(pidof prog)/fd` to find out the opened files of some `prog`

Comment: the output is in _basic.nii.gz_ format files. However, when I type in `watch ls -l basic.nii.gz` it says that no such file or directory exists

Comment: Some utilities rename temporarily the output.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @basile-starynkevitch answer,
I have a bash script that can measure how much file did you processed in percents.

It watch into `procfs` get current position from fd information (`/proc/pid/fdinfo`), and count this in percents, relative to total file size.

See https://gist.github.com/azat/2830255

```
curl -s https://gist.github.com/azat/2830255/raw >| progress_fds.sh \
&& chmod +x progress_fds.sh

Usage:
./progress_fds.sh /path/to/file [ PID]
```

Сan be useful to someone

Comment: I took your script as an inspiration and extended the mechanism a little.  My Python script can be viewed at https://code.activestate.com/recipes/578882-monitor-progress-of-file-descriptors-of-another-pr/ .

Comment: Yeah, @Alfe nice improvement, I will look into this! Thanks!

Comment: concise and extremely useful, this should have many more up votes

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the syscalls of a program by using `strace`, which will enable you to follow the `open` calls.

Comment: Are you supposed to specify `strace` within the command line or you could sequentially type it in? @thiton

Comment: (Both:) You can either `strace` a command or an already running process.

Answer (score 1):

You can use verbose output, but it will slow things down even more.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there can't be a general answer to that, it just depends on the type of program (that doesn't even has to do anything with Linux, see the "halting problem").

If you happen to use a pipe during the conversion I find the [`pv(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pv) tool pretty helpful. Even if `pv` can't know the total size of the data it helps to see if there is actual progress and how good the datarate is. It isn't part of most standard installations though and probably has to be installed explicitly.